# Opening a 7z file on mac shows strange encodings

Tags: encoding, 7-zip, unicode, character-encoding, unzip

I am opening this file:

https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?fileId=2901965&version=1.0

On TextEdit. When I do, the file looks like:

```
7zºØ'·   t(ù‚]%N
ò„,¢‡ò]¬CRJ∫√ıìaIÄÅ≤íhYTÔ1/ıG3À=ôN’(Æ¯∞”(3:|
ÙˆıÍ¬âù∞ºä1ßôÆs≈Ë W≥VUiI'W˜Ì¢<~"k˙⁄ oÓéeññwƒI◊£gÉô.Wx8µ2¸ıMägz‰j¨•À√ÇfcÚ®[/ÿpˇË5Éßil«ànQ∫
‘#G≥Ëm-;>[?   X   Á∑ﬂ§Ø∏Íõ®‡„ö≈©h.D"<VªŒµœwâæB€ÜÏ+*¥`°àU‘\Ÿ~4cç®+˛˛~Î
ä(˘ﬁ™üÛÏ5$ÕŸ3—Ô—OU>‚˘®m`ÉJ±í“]¸û0ôyÙw‚Ó~t`8Âkê˙õ’§µìKwò3=2÷ãËŒRÄXƒ8°zòJ9!
1˚âÓÄh√]Y+ÅYŸ;1r«(y_¢_ÀU_Â8O*Ÿª®Öj"!ä+öΩÌïºn∆â5èûRÜlN∆ºﬂUí¿y@ö))kR¡3’∑PÄ
û@'›˜¬‘%*áÚ‘ˇøÁX”æt/Oú~ÿ&Å  ùËº–C—-MDöLIW%+Éy∫%i˙N 0
```

How can I actually view this file properly, even using the command line? It consists of several Tweets.

Answer (score 0):

[.7z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z) is a compressed archive file format. On a Mac you can use [keka](http://www.kekaosx.com) for decompressing.

Comment: Isn't this the same as WinZip? OK so I don't have to unzip I actually have to decompress.